# wordpress flexslider is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm developing custom theme for wordpress and using `META SLIDER` plugin for that, but in rendering page. in firebug result that says:

```
$(...).flexslider is not a function
```

line 242 :

```
useCSS:false
```

full attached java script with plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var metaslider_99 = function($) {
        $('#metaslider_99').flexslider({ 
            slideshowSpeed:3000,
            animation:"fade",
            controlNav:true,
            directionNav:true,
            pauseOnHover:true,
            direction:"horizontal",
            reverse:false,
            animationSpeed:600,
            prevText:"<",
            nextText:">",
            easing:"linear",
            slideshow:true,
            useCSS:false
        });
    };
    var timer_metaslider_99 = function() {
        var slider = !window.jQuery ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_99, 100) : !jQuery.isReady ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_99, 100) : metaslider_99(window.jQuery);
    };
    timer_metaslider_99();
</script>
```

Is this an issue of the order of the stacking of the javascript files?

LINK:
[Please see this link](http://niniha.com/?p=59)

Comment: I can't see `flexislider()` anywhere on that page?

Comment: @BenM. in source of page can view error of that. slider do not work

Comment: I don't see any error in the page source. Output stops at `<div class="footer-niniha">کلیه حقوق مادی و معنوی این سایت متعلق به نی‌نی‌ها می‌باشد.</div>`

Comment: @BenM. FireBug can display error on console. can you test with it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I get the error: `GET http://niniha.com/?p=59 404 (Not Found) `

Comment: @BenM. it does not have any problem. i can see this page without problem. i'm publish again. please try again thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your theme looks like it's missing a call to wp_footer() (it looks like its missing the whole footer.php actually).

Meta Slider needs this in place in order to enqueue the correct JavaScript and CSS files.

Please see this page:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer